# PHP email encoding

Tags: php, email, utf-8, character-encoding

Any ideas what could be wrong with my code? Every time somebody fills out my web form using national characters (-eg.:   ž, š, ô, í) the email created by PHP script looks like this:

I tried fixing it by adding "charset=utf-8" to headers, but that doesn't seem to work.

"MÃ”Å½E BYÅ¤ nÃ¡ moÅ¾nosÅ¥"

My code:

```
<?php
if($_POST['parse_var'] == "contactform"){

   $emailTitle = 'Application Form';
   $yourEmail = 'myMail@myMailService.com';

   $nameField = $_POST['name'];
   $streetField = $_POST['street'];
   $cityField = $_POST['city'];
   $ZIP_codeField = $_POST['ZIP_code'];
   $cell_phoneField = $_POST['cell_phone'];
   $emailField = $_POST['email'];



   $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Parent: $nameField <br />
Street: $streetField <br />
City: $cityField <br />
ZIP: $ZIP_codeField <br />
Mobile: $cell_phoneField <br />
Email: $emailField <br />


EOD;

    $headers = "From: skola@athena-academy.sk\r\n";

    $headers .= "Reply-To: $emailField\r\n";

        $headers.= "Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 

    $success = mail("$yourEmail", "$emailTitle", "$body", "$headers");  

   $sent = "Your email has been sent";


}

?>
```

Comment: Is your form UTF-8 as well?

Comment: I think so.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...and so on.
<meta charset = "UTF-8">

Comment: Is the browser actually showing UTF-8 in the encoding menu when you go to the form?

Comment: I don't know where to check that.

Comment: Every browser has an "encoding" menu that shows which encoding the browser uses for the current site. It could be named something like "character set"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_http_output( "UTF-8" );
ob_start("mb_output_handler");
```

?>

Comment: I'm an absolute PHP noob - I "created" my script following a youtube tutorial. Could you please tell me where to paste these three lines of your code?

Comment: try to put it in top page or your page (index.php ,contact.php )whatever .

Comment: mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_http_output( "UTF-8" );
ob_start("mb_output_handler");